# xml substring from to string key in php

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to string between  to  from this XML string 
used explode string but not getting proper result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Response>
    <responseCode>000</responseCode>
     <inputcheck>
    <input>
        <paramName>rdono</paramName>
        <paramValue>121212</paramValue>
    </input>
    <input>
        <paramName>set</paramName>
        <paramValue>7878</paramValue>
    </input>
</inputcheck>
<responserst>
    <optionst>
        <option>
            <amountName>Early</amountName>
            <amountValue>34000</amountValue>
        </option>
        <option>
            <amountName>Late</amountName>
            <amountValue>35000</amountValue>
        </option>
    </optionst>
    <valuno>35000</valuno>
    <valunodate>2019-10-15</valunodate>
</responserst>
<additionalInfo>
    <info>
        <infoName>PC</infoName>
        <infoValue>5</infoValue>
    </info>
    <info>
        <infoName>Disconn Tag</infoName>
        <infoValue>0</infoValue>
    </info>
</additionalInfo>
</Response>
```

i tried with explode and substring but it is not working 
Please help me solve this problem

i need output like this

```
<inputcheck>
<input>
    <paramName>rdono</paramName>
    <paramValue>121212</paramValue>
</input>
<input>
    <paramName>set</paramName>
    <paramValue>7878</paramValue>
</input>
</inputcheck>
```

Comment: Please post the problem you have got

Comment: [Working as intended](https://3v4l.org/pqiQ3), though it's a very weird (and almost certainly bad) thing to do. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What is your expected output, also why aren't you using XML tools rather than string manipulation?

Comment: Look at `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath` - you will manage to solve the problem very easily with them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the correct tools for processing XML you will find the task quite simple. Load the XML string into `DOMDocument` and then create an XPath processor ( `DOMXPath` ) so you can run queries against the DOM. You could, alternatively, forgo the XPath processor and use `parent` and `sibling` selectors but that gets a little more complicated

```
$xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <Response>
            <responseCode>000</responseCode>
            <inputcheck>
                <input>
                    <paramName>rdono</paramName>
                    <paramValue>121212</paramValue>
                </input>
                <input>
                    <paramName>set</paramName>
                    <paramValue>7878</paramValue>
                </input>
            </inputcheck>
            <responserst>
                <optionst>
                    <option>
                        <amountName>Early</amountName>
                        <amountValue>34000</amountValue>
                    </option>
                    <option>
                        <amountName>Late</amountName>
                        <amountValue>35000</amountValue>
                    </option>
                </optionst>
                <valuno>35000</valuno>
                <valunodate>2019-10-15</valunodate>
            </responserst>
            <additionalInfo>
                <info>
                    <infoName>PC</infoName>
                    <infoValue>5</infoValue>
                </info>
                <info>
                    <infoName>Disconn Tag</infoName>
                    <infoValue>0</infoValue>
                </info>
            </additionalInfo>
        </Response>';

libxml_use_internal_errors( true );
$dom=new DOMDocument;
$dom->validateOnParse=false;
$dom->recover=true;
$dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
$dom->loadXML( $xml );
$errors = libxml_get_errors();
libxml_clear_errors();




$xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
$col=$xp->query( '//inputcheck/input' );

function nodevalue( $tag, $parent ){# helper
    global $xp;
    return $xp->query( $tag, $parent )->item( 0 )->textContent;
}       


foreach( $col as $node ){
    $name=nodevalue( 'paramName', $node );
    $value=nodevalue( 'paramValue', $node );

    echo $name, $value;
}
```

Will output:

```
rdono121212set7878
```

Comment: You can replace the `nodevalue()` calls with `$name = $xp->evaluate('string(paramName)', $node); $value = $xp->evaluate('string(paramValue)', $node); `. It will return an empty string if here is no matching node.